# How to store data in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to store some data which I received from my server into a file in my android project. But I'm not able to do that.. I used the following code which I've shown below.. Please help me out someone. Thanks.

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

The error its giving is "Content cannot be resolved to a variable". I imported android.content.. Then its giving an error for all the 3 lines called "Unhandled Exception type FileNotFoundException"
But I have created that file.. The problem is that I'm not knowing in which folder of the project do I keep that file? Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two way of saving a data is allowed in Android that is by using SharedPreference or Sqlite DB
File writing is not advisable.

For your Question
1. Manifest Should have write permission.

If not please send the code.. Its very basic

My suggestion is SharedPreference for you.

Comment: shared preference is not suggested for large amount of data

Comment: Ohk sure I'll try that thanks. I should learn shared preferences now.

Comment: Pratheek, please tick which ever answer helps you, So it can be used for others. And people are spending some time for you to resolve this issue.If not checked, So many people can help others who are in need. I agree with Usman.

Comment: Ranjith, yeah sure I'll do that once I figure out which solution is working. But the problem is that I'm still a beginner in android development and so I'm taking a hell lot of a time to implement and test stuff. Sorry for the inconvenience everyone :(

Answer (score 1):

**-** The most common mistake to take place here is that you have **not** given the `permission to wite external storage` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**-** Please include this into your manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this. Bt even though i added that <uses-permission> element, its still not working. Can u please tell me in which folder should I place that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
File root = context.getFilesDir();

File file = new File(root, fileName);
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: Where should I include this? Inside the onCreate() function itself?

Comment: You add it where the file needs to be saved.

Comment: It is giving an error called fos cannot be resolved to a variable. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

1st check the Manifest Permission as suggested by Kumar 
if still not sorted your problem out then take a look at the following [link](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-23%E2%80%93Writing-and-Reading-Files) to get Help